# v-for key property or method is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm getting this error every time I trigger the opening of a new `BoostrapVue` tab:

```
Property or method "i" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

This is my component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <b-card no-body>
            <b-tabs card>
                <b-tab v-for="order in tabs" :key="i">
                    <template slot="title">
                        <div>{{ order.name }}</div>
                        <b-button type="button" class="close float-right" aria-label="Close" @click="closeTab(order.id)">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </b-button>
                    </template>
                    <items-table
                            ref="itemsTable"
                            name="items-table"
                    ></items-table>
                </b-tab>
            </b-tabs>
        </b-card>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'table-tabs',
        data() {
            return {
                tabs: [],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            closeTab(id) {
                for (let i = 0; i < this.tabs.length; i++) {
                    if (this.tabs[i].id === id) {
                        this.tabs.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }
            },
            newTab(order) {
                this.tabs.push(order);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

How do I get this warning to stop showing up for `:key="i"`?

Vue.js v2.5.12
BootstrapVue 2.0.0-rc11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never defined `i`, the easiest way to do so is in the loop itself:

```
<b-tab v-for="(order, i) in tabs" :key="i">
```

This way `i` will be the current index for each item.

However, the `key` attribute is an optimization method of the templating engine to determine wether it should re-render a node or not. If your orders do have a unique identifier (which it looks like to me) you could use this instead to actually get a benefit using `key`:

```
<b-tab v-for="(order, i) in tabs" :key="order.id">
```